# Errors in Spring MVC appfuse app in Eclipse

Tags: m2eclipse, m2e, appfuse

I have build a Spring MVC multimodule app using Appfuse. It works fine when ran through MVN Jetty:run. I am able to build and run the app very well through maven. But When I imported all the modules in Eclipse through M2E it is giving me so many errors I am going to copy the errors here can someone please help me resolve them?

I named my project as mynewproject when I built it using Appfuse.

1) I am getting below error :

The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path

in all the JSP files in base module "mynewproject".

2)I have issues with application-context-dao.xml

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-
     context-3.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read;  the root element of the document is not 
     .
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.

3) Multiple errors in applicationContextService.xml for AOP config and above mentioned error for context config again.

4)Sample-data.xsd has content in some different language and it gives error :

Content is not allowed in prolog.

In module mynewproject-core I have following error in pom.xml

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:operation (execution: test-compile, phase: test-compile)

And finally in mynewproject-web has an error :

Syntax error on token "ne", invalid AssignmentOperator

for the line :

Can someone please help with these errors.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 4)Sample-data.xsd has content in some different language and it gives
>   error :
>
> Content is not allowed in prolog.

I am not sure if you have resolved the problems, for this error, you can open the file on github and copy the content into your local file. The url is https://github.com/appfuse/appfuse/blob/34dc1599636e15ab9e0372d67542321e25f1896c/web/common/src/test/resources/sample-data.xsd. I am also trying to fix other errors. For this one,

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.codehaus.mojo:dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:operation (execution:
>   test-compile, phase: test-compile)

I fixed it by choosing "Mark ignore" by right clicking as a quick fix in Eclipse, that works for me for now.

> Syntax error on token "ne", invalid AssignmentOperator

For this one, I modified it to another string and then use Maven to update project, and it is fixed.

I will update this answer once I find resolutions to other problems.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error right click on project, click Properties. Select appropriate application server (Tomcat, vFabric, Glassfish, etc.) from Target Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest some solutions that might help resolve all issues you're facing or whoever because I've faced the same issue before.

1. **"The superclass 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet' was not found on the Java Build Path..." issue.**
   Since you said are using m2e plugin in you eclipse IDE and the web pom have already listed java.servlet as dependency, you should have that lib in your local repo when doing mvn jetty:run. Otherwise, in this case, I suggest you to perform maven update for web project. Just right-click on the project root and select Maven->Update Project. Make sure you have the Project->Build Automatically turn on, it should show some positive result.
2. **"application-context-dao.xml..." issue.**
   if you're having "application-context-dao.xml" file, that means you probably have ran mvn appfuse:full-source. Based on your info, Eclipse IDE may have reported xml validation errors against "declared" XSDs. There are a few things you can do:

   - Make sure your internet connection is good so that the XSDs can be referenced by the validation process.
   - Make sure all schemas pointed by in the **xsi:schemaLocation** are accessible and valid.
   - If all the above are good, make sure the xml entries are correct and well-formed. Then you may want to try to manually validate by right clicking on the document editing area and select "Validate".
3. **"applicationContextService.xml for AOP config..." issue.**
   You could apply the same as suggested in the previous issue.
4. **"Sample-data.xsd..." issue.**
   Open up the same file in your favorite text editor, select-all, copy and paste replacing all them in same file in Eclipse IDE.
5. **"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration..." issue.**
   Just wrap <plugins>..</plugins> with <pluginManagement>...</pluginManagement>
6. **"Syntax error on token 'ne', invalid AssignmentOperator..." issue.**
   Replace them the with "!=" (without the quotes).

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have successfully deployed this app a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just few of the answers:

**4**. *Sample-data.xsd has content...*

It's seems to be bug of Eclipse. You can make 'workaround' for it if you open it in some text editor (not Eclipse), and change value of encoding from utf-a6 to utf-8, like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**6**. *Syntax error on token "ne"...*

Also problem with Eclipse, it isn't AppFuse bug. Just try to change 'ne' operator with another equivalent which is *!=* like on following:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.locale.language != 'en'}">
```

P.S. I've just seen that you've already solved the problem but it could be useful to someone else :)